# php - MySQL remove selected items from html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a html table inside a form with checkbox buttons on each item, this table shows all rows from a table in my database. I want to be able to click the check boxes, then click the remove button i added to remove the selected items from the database.

Here is the code for the individual table items:

```
<tr>
  <th scope='row'><div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='$id'></label>
  </div></th>
      <th scope='row'>$id</th>
  <td>$name</td>
  <td>$description</td>
  <td>$price</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, for the checkbox name as the id in the database. I am using the POST method for the form, how can i remove the selected check boxes in php?

Comment: Surely Google would have found many results for this. What did you find and try, honestly now.

Comment: start by echoing out the post data into a <pre> block then you can get a decent look at what is coming through and see what you are working with. then you will need to loop through the post data and extract the parts you need (the checkbox ids probably) then you will run all those ids in a delete query for the table in question. All the while, sanitizing, securing and generally validating nothing can go wrong and wipe out the database.

Comment: A: hidden input and `foreach`. Good luck and good night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post the PHP, it will give you this:

```
$_POST = array(
  "21" => "on",
  "42" => "on",
  "64" => "on"
);
```

Assuming, the `21, 42, 64` are the selected IDs. Now you just need to do this:

```
array_keys($_POST); // [21, 42, 64]
$ids = implode(", ", array_keys($_POST)); // "21, 42, 64"
```

Use SQL to give this:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN ($ids);
```

The above SQL, when combined with the right PHP, gets transformed into:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (21, 42, 64);
```

The above SQL will remove the records.

Comment: I have more variables other than the checkboxes. any solution for that?

Comment: @ItzBulkDev Use `name='chk[$id]'` and instead of `$_POST`, use `$_POST["chk"]`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar IMHO, I'd use a hidden input and a `foreach`, but that's just me. I'd of posted my own answer but at this stage, fear being chased down somewhere.

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while but theres a problem, it wont delete from the database                                                                                                <?php
if(isset($_POST["chk"])){

include '../database/Database.php';

array_keys($_POST["chk"]);
$ids = implode(", ", array_keys($_POST["chk"])); 

$delete = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN ($ids);";
$deletes = $conn->query($deletes);

echo "<h3 class='ct3'><font color='green'>Deleted products: $ids</font></h3>";
}
?>